# create a foreign key to a column that exists on another server over a database link?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-link

In Oracle 11g is it possilble to create a foreign key to a column that exists on another server over a database link?

If so is there a query I could use to find them all?

Comment: Sorry didn't find that one in my search... Thanks.